# Javascript Rendering HTML with ".append" - Simple Code Explanation

Tags: javascript, append

Can Anyone explain what each line of this code means? I'm trying to move the `<script>` call statement to a specific position in my HTML but the code generated by my script always moves this to the bottom of one particular table and I think it has something to do with this code. I would prefer to position it myself by rewriting this function to insert the code at the point where the `<script>` appears in the HTML.

```
function initialize(instance) {
        _this = instance;
        // build html
        var realCaller = caller != null? caller:$("body");
        var cornerClass = options.showRoundCorner? "ui-corner-all ":"";
        realCaller.append("<div id='"+windowId+"' class='window_panel "+cornerClass+options.containerClass+"'></div>");
        container = realCaller.children("div#"+windowId);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to know without context.

Comment: Do you have a link to this code running in context?

Comment: I do.. it's at http://freemanfoxx.com/2home

Comment: Do you know if the page is running jQuery, or MooTools, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<script>` tag should be left wherever it was originally. Moving it around will not help.

I am assuming the page is using jQuery, but I can't tell for sure from what you've posted.

First, you need to put an `id` attribute on the page element where you want the HTML to be inserted (i.e. `<div id="your_id_here"></div>`. Then, change this line:

```
var realCaller = caller != null? caller:$("body");
```

To this:

```
var realCaller = $('#your_id_here');
```

Replacing "your_id_here" with the ID that you set on the page element.

**Note:** Since you posted so little of your code, it's hard to know whether this "fix" will break other parts of the code....

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I've been trying to do. My only problem now is to figure out why it is rendering the box at the lower right hand corner or the screen! I've updated it's position to relative inside the "facebook_container" div but the "left" and "top" attributes are being set by the javascript somewhere in here: http://freemanfoxxrealty.com/wp-content/themes/freemanfoxx/js/ui.jquery.window.js

Comment: You're Awesome, Mark! Thank you -- the file that contains the code is the one I linked to above.

Comment: I see you are calling a function called `createFacebookWindow()`... it would seem that you are using JavaScript that is specifically designed to display the content in a "floating" window, rather than inline.

Comment: The ui.jquery.window.js file is just a jQuery plugin. It doesn't "do" *anything* unless you tell it to. We need to examine the code that is setting this thing up. Specifically, I'd like to know where the `createFacebookWindow()` function is.

Comment: Mark -- yeah -- you're right.. it was designed to be floating with absolute positioning. Once the browser loads the page, however, if the page is resized and the content isn't reloaded, the positioning of the element kept getting screwed up. So I decided to move it into a relatively positioned element. I believe the code you're looking for is here: http://freemanfoxxrealty.com/wp-content/themes/freemanfoxx/js/ui.index.js

Comment: Hmm... so describe exactly what you're wanting it to do, and exactly where it is supposed to be positioned, etc. You want it in that box in the middle of the page?

Comment: yep -- I'm needing the "FreemanFoxx Updates" box to be positioned directly above the empty gray box with the same title here: http://freemanfoxxrealty.com/2home. The trick is, it can't be positioned absolute because when if someone changes the browser window size it will start moving.

Comment: Got it. The trouble is, I'm not familiar with the Window plugin... reading through the docs now.

Comment: The idea is that I'll eventually be creating a box for each of these.. this is just my first one that I want to get put together perfectly and then use as a template. I can't tell you how much I appreciate your helping me out with this, Mark. As you can tell, I'm not very proficient with code.. I've been faking my way through it for years and it makes me bang my head up against the wall every time I take on a project like this one..

Comment: Honestly, I don't think the Window plugin is meant to be abused in this way. You can put a window within a specific container (which you have done - in the `<td id="main">` element), but the plugin seems to always calculate position relative to the page. I think you'll be better off writing about 5 lines of code to position it yourself, rather than using this plugin. I'm going to try to write something simple.

Comment: lol.. yeah -- "abuse" is the right word. Let me see if I can come up with something.. thanks for your help, Mark.

Comment: Basically what you want is for the box to expand to the full width of the page, maintaining the same height, right?

Comment: pretty much - it should expand to fill the area where the other boxes are.. one box will expand and cover the others..

Comment: there's another div with the ID "main" which was used as the placeholder for the maximized boxes.. they filled it to 100% and it worked great

Comment: I think I got it to work. Remove the position:relative from #facebook_container and the position:absolute from #facebook_content. Then the box seems to properly adjust itself when I resize the browser. Or perhaps I've just misunderstood what you wanted.

Comment: yeah -- that's exactly how it's been for me from the beginning.. let me keep playing with it to see if I can figure this out..

Comment: I'm writing something from scratch. It's working pretty well so far. I'll let you know when I have it done.

Comment: I'm going to owe you a drink! Maybe we can salvage some of the code from the Window jQuery plugin..

Comment: well, I got it working, but I had to just hack out the "left: 390px" and "top: 473" by cancelling them out with negative positions in the relative DIV in which the box sits.. it works now but I'm not sure how stable it is..

Comment: Here's what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/marke/3Cz8z/ Let me know if you need help adapting it to your markup.

Comment: Oops, be sure to remove this line from my JS: `console.log(box.offset());`

Comment: that's awesome, Mark! and way better than the hacked version I have.. the only question I have is, would it be very complicted to implement some of the jQuery animations to the maximize toggle? can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: With animation: http://jsfiddle.net/marke/3Cz8z/2/ - I rewrote the JS in pretty substantial ways, so make sure you re-copy all of it. There is now some code that runs when the page loads, to re-position all the `.content` elements relative to the `.boundary`. The CSS/HTML did not change.

Answer (score 2):

```
function initialize(instance) {
        _this = instance; //  _this is now equal to the instance variable.
        // build html
        var realCaller = caller != null? caller:$("body"); // if caller isn't null make realCaller equal to caller otherwise the body element
        var cornerClass = options.showRoundCorner? "ui-corner-all ":""; // same deal here
        realCaller.append("<div id='"+windowId+"' class='window_panel  "+cornerClass+options.containerClass+"'></div>"); // append this element to corner class variable
        container = realCaller.children("div#"+windowId); // container equals all children within the realcaller object.
```

Comment: Well, almost. It appears to be jQuery, in which case `realCaller` is a jQuery object containing the `body` element. Subsequently, `container` would be the div child of the body with the id `windowId`, not all children. It could be another JS library, though. The fact is, we can only make an educated guess about what `$` really is here.