# Javascript Dialog Box Animation - Final Tweak

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I've been working with the freakin' amazing [Mark Eirich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387347/mark-eirich) on reworking a Javascript dialog box [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280396) and he has set something up in JSFiddle that is going to help a lot but I need help finishing off one little part. I need the boxes to fill both the width AND the height of the container box.

Can anyone take a look and see if you have any suggestions? If you could explain how to do it that would be awesome. I'm really trying to understand this.

http://jsfiddle.net/QhsRj/

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind.. I got it!! Woo Hoo!!!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/QhsRj/24/